# Moving data from one workbook to another when a certain field is completed

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked at numerous other posts but have not been able to find a workable solution to a problem I am having. Firstly, I am a total newbie with VBA and I do mean total.
I have a spreadsheet where a date is input when we successfully make contact with someone. This data then needs to be cut and pasted onto a master archive so we can prove we have called them if required. What I need is a way to cut and paste the whole line the data is on, onto a workbook which will store the data. My plan is to have 7 workbooks feeding into one master but the master can have 7 tabs if that makes things easier. I can supply the spreadsheet I am working on if required.

I have tried the following code but it seems to copy a row above each time leading to blank rows on the master sheet (they're actually showing as gold but i think that's to do with the formatting of surrounding cells)....

```
Sub deleterow()

'Using autofilter to copy rows that have a completed date field to a new 
worksheet

Dim LR As Long
Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
LR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 3
LR1 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M3:M" & LR)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", VisibleDropDown:=True
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & LR1)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Need clarification.  There are seven little Indians, each with their own workbooks.  They each record a date when they call some one on their own workbooks.  You want a Master Workbook to open all seven workbooks and get those dates.  Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When contact is made with a customer a date is input in column "M". When column "M" is populated, that row of data will be cut from that workbook and pasted onto the master. So, yeah, basically what you said. :-)

Comment: if your master can have 7 sheets then why the need for 7 workbooks?